# HTML 5 - Drag n Drop - ondragover event not triggered if the drop target is fully occupied

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-events

I have a container with a left panel and a right panel. You can drag from the left panel, and drop on the right panel. For some reason, the html 5 `onDragOver` event is not triggered if the drop target is already completely occupied. My drop target is a div, and I would be dynamically creating iframes in it when `onDrop` event occurs. I am able to create the 1st iframe when I drag something for the first time from left and drop it to left. But now for the 2nd time if I drag something from the left and try to drop it to right, the `onDragOver` is not getting triggered(I put the breakpoint, it's not getting hit), because the drop target is already full with my 1st iframe. In the `onDragOver` listener I would like to reduce the height of existing iframe to half, so as to make room for creation of new iframe. But unfortunately the onDragOver is just not getting triggered. Is there any way I can modify the behaviour of onDragOver, so that it gets triggered even if the drop target is completely occupied? Any help would be greatly appreciated. So, here is the code ..

```
function onDragOver(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 if(iframes_count > 4)
 {
   return;
 }
 if (iframes_count == 2)
 {
    if ((getDivLeftCoordinate() < ev.pageX < getDroppableWidth()) && (getDivTopCoordinate() < ev.pageY < getDroppableHeight()/2))
    {
        var existingFrames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i = 0; i < existingFrames.length; i++)
        {
          $(this).attr("height" , 500);
        }
    }
 }
 $("#right_pane").css("background-color", "grey");
}

function onDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();

var data_id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var data_id_selector= "#" + data_id;
var content_id = data_id + "content";
var content_id_selector = "#" + content_id;
var url = $(data_id_selector).data("url");
var iframe_width = 100 + "%";
var iframe_height = 100 + "%";


$(data_id_selector).remove();
$("<iframe />", {
class: "myFrame",
id : content_id,

}).appendTo('#right_pane');



$(content_id_selector).attr("height", iframe_height);
$(content_id_selector).attr("width", iframe_width);
$(content_id_selector).attr("src", url);
$(content_id_selector).attr("background-color", "white");
$("#right_pane").css("background-color", "white");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps just a syntax issue, the event in HTML5 is `dragover` (no `on`)

more html5 drag n drop info here:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/dnd.html
- http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/
- http://html5demos.com/drag

Comment: No, its not a syntax issue. I am using w3schools documentation for reference.

Comment: @Tejas You really should read up on this site, http://w3fools.com/, why you should not use w3schools.com.